# Restart a visual studio project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, application-restart

I am using *MS Visual Studio 2010* to run an application. The application is being run from the project for various reasons. At one point I need to *restart* the program as it is done exactly by this button [image].

I searched around for batch file code but I found none to undertake this task also tried the `Application.restart` but no luck so far. Can you help me?

Comment: Why doesn't `Application.Restart()` work for you?

Comment: because it created multiple instances in process and crushes all the server. as this is done 100s of times everday

Comment: Then you must have put it in a bad place, causing it to execute several times before the application exits. What happens if you create a shared boolean variable that you set to `True` once you've called `Restart()`, then check that before restarting, i.e: `If RestartInitiated = False Then Application.Restart() : RestartInitiated = True`?